# Log4net & NUnit: Test only succeeds once, subsequent tests fail because log file "used by another process"

Tags: locking, nunit, log4net

My open source .NET software uses Log4net with zero problems.

But when I test it with NUnit, I get the error below at the **second** test. For instance, if I run a test twice, it will succeed the first time and fail the second time, whatever the test:

> System.IO.IOException : The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\win7pro32bit\AppData\Roaming\cmissync\debug_log.txt' because it is being used by another process.

The log file is created by [a static call to log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(path)](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/blob/master/CmisSync/TestLibrary/CmisSyncTests.cs#L76)

I guess I should somehow close the log file in TearDown, but I can't see any log4net "close" method.

Adding `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />` to [the log4net configuration](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/blob/master/CmisSync.Lib/Config.cs#L289) fixes the problem, but this [degrades performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999382/intermittent-log4net-rollingfileappender-locked-file-issue), so I would prefer a test-side solution, that has no impact on production code.

Comment: Set the LockingModel to MinimalLock programatically during TestInitialize

Comment: Do you actually *need* the logging in the tests? If not (you shouldn't unless you are specifically testing the logging), don't configure it and the problem goes away.

Comment: I usually use `<appender name="ConsoleLog" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">` in my tests.  It gets put in the output window and this gets saved anyway in the unit test results.

Comment: @stuartd: TestInitialize seems to be mstest... I guess the NUnit equivalent is `[SetUp]`? (run before each test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by adrianbanks and Cole W in the comments, I don't really need to log to a file.

So this solved the problem:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(new TraceAppender());
    }
```