# how to switch log4net multiple log files using C# code?

Tags: log4net

I'm using log4net, I would like to have 2 logs,
- BasketballCustomer.log, for all Customers that plays Basketball;
- ChessCustomer.log, for all Customers that plays Chess.
, while for each customer, whether he/she plays Basketball or Chess, is only known until runtime.

I would like to have each log configured separately, about log file name, size, number, log level, etc.

Also, I'd prefer such set up done by C# code, not config file.

How could I do that?

I tried search on net, there are some articles but none meet exactly my requirements
- [Log4Net and multiple log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849105/log4net-and-multiple-log-files) talked about multiple log files but it does not toggle during runtime;
- [Configure Log4net to write to multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372435/configure-log4net-to-write-to-multiple-files) is similiar but it's done in config file....

Please kindly suggest, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using an environment variable in the log4net.config and then set the value of the environment variable through the C# code

So somewhere in your C# class, do something like:

`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("log_file_name", "MyLogFileName");`

And then in the log4net.config that is used, specify the value to the name of the environment variable. The syntax would be something like this:

`<param name="File" value="${log_file_name}".log/>`