# Generate identical files from log4net

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

[Similar question to here but slightly different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372435/configure-log4net-to-write-to-multiple-files)

Like the attached link I am trying to get log4net to output to multiple (x2) files.
As opposed to the link I am looking to have the same information sent to both files. For some reason only the first log file is being generated (Logs.log) and not the second (LogsTest.log)

Can anyone shine some light on this for me please?

```
<log4net>
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="Logs.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <threshold value="INFO" />
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <levelMin value="INFO" />
            <levelMax value="OFF" />
        </filter>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
        <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %P{url} %P{usr} %P{addr} – %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="LogsTest.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <threshold value="INFO" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="INFO" />
      <levelMax value="OFF" />
    </filter>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
    <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %P{url} %P{usr} %P{addr} – %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
    <logger name="PlaceGen">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender1" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Config looks right - are you definitely using the "PlaceGen" logger to log, as there's no root element defined here?

Comment: Yeah (well a name that I have replaced it with)
Don't get it, RollingFileAppender is generating perfectly but the one ending with ...1? Not a thing

Comment: Add a breakpoint where you do the logging, and from there inspect the appenders associated with the logger by adding a watch on `log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().OfType<RollingFileAppender>()`. If they're both there, check for misconfiguration messages by inspecting `log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().ConfigurationMessages.Cast<LogLog>()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have been smart to have the local operator to restart the application first