# Is it possible to have custom loggers hierarchy in log4net.config?

Tags: logging, log4net, dry, log4net-configuration

I don't want to use normal hierarchy rules dependent on code. Can I specify a custom one in log4net.config?

I mean that now hierarchy is automatically figured out by dots in logger name like `First.Second.Third` => `First` inherits `root` settings, `Second` inherits `First`, `Third` inherits `Second`, but assume I want to specify that `First.Second.Third` should inherit `root2` settings. Is it possible?

I need this to remove duplication in logger settings where normally `root` settings are ok but for some loggers I want to specify other settings without doing it separately for each logger.

Comment: You can only have one root element.

Comment: @stuartd is it possible to have 2 "sub-roots" inherited by different loggers?

Comment: Not _nicely_, as you would need to use the sub-root names in the logger names - so you would have `Root1.First.Second` and `Root2.First.Second.Third` which removes the convenience of just being able to use the enclosing type name as the logger name.

Comment: @stuartd, I don't want to change logger names in code just to configure things in log4net.config

Comment: of course not, which is what I was trying to say. One alternative might be to use [multiple repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706713/log4net-logging-to-multiple-defined-appenders-using-class-name-loggers/36719549#36719549)