# Second Log4net logger not writing to unique file

Tags: c#, log4net

I have an application that is using Anotar.Log4Net for logging.  I cannot strip out the Anotar.Log4Net as other team members are using it. I would like to add my own logging file.  I added an additional file appender to my app.config called BGDEV. I reviewed the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372435/configure-log4net-to-write-to-multiple-files/1372464) to see how other's are accomplishing the task of having two file appenders.  The desired behavior below is for each logger to log to it's own file. Everything is logging to MainLog.txt. Is this because there is something wrong with the app.config settings or because I have the anotar library installed?

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="MainLog.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="BGDEV" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="BG_Log.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</root>
<logger additivity="false" name="BGDev">
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="BGDev" />
</logger>
```

In code I create a logger and use it.  Is there something wrong with my config file or is this becaise I am using

```
private static readonly ILog otherLog = LogManager.GetLogger("BGDEV");
otherLog.Info("TEST OTHER LOG");
```

Comment: Log4Net appender names are case-sensitive; you need to reconcile "BGDev" and "BGDEV"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with naming in your code and config. Names are case sensitive - you're defining a logger named `BGDev`, but you call `GetLogger("BGDEV")`, since no logger named `BGDEV` exists, it falls back to the root logger.

Your logger named `BGDev` also references an appender named `BGDev`, however again, no such appender exists, since you are defining it with an all-uppercase name `BGDEV`.

Finally, your `BGDev` logger needs to have a `<layout>...</layout>` section, or it won't be able to format log messages.

If you fix these issues, it should work as you expect.